# Dos script to extract X number of lines

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a script to:
- Ask the user for customer number (max 8 Digits)

- Search a very large text file for that #
  (Source.txt)
- Extract 19 lines of text above customer # (everything as is, including empty lines)
- The line number of customer # would be line 20 in this case.
- Extract line 20
- Extract the next 30 lines below the customer #.
- Save all extracted output in: Output.txt

Basically like copying a block of text and pasting in new text file.

In the source text file, customer# location is  not random line number.

Comment: `grep` from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard linux command-line utilities (on windows too) like **cat**,  **grep** and **output redirection** (in bash script, for example) as follow.

```
# read and validate customer number (stdin, parameter, ...)
cat Source.txt | grep '12345678' -A 30 -B 19 > Output.txt
```

where `12345678` is customer number, `-B` specifies number of lines before and `-A` number of lines after match with customer number.